# Show .gif animation when control is not there in the c# (windows) application

Tags: c#, php, progress-bar, animated-gif

I have one application in that i am calling a .php file using webClient from the server. To complete the process it takes few minutes(based on the client db). I tried to show progress bar but because of control is not here it's not processing . It updating when it completes the download process. So now i am trying to show .gif image but same thing happening with the image also. Any other solutions are there??????

Comment: a better choice is to show a progress bar in another form "Waiting Form" and when the download process finished close the waiting form.

Comment: thanks. I tried but it's also not showing when control is not in the application. and it's not showing image also in the waiting form just it shoeing blank form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You'd want to do your time-consuming tasks in a separate (non-UI) thread, and let the UI thread do the message processing, which in turn redraws your progress bar and animates GIFs.

Comment: @deepi Unfortunatelly, this is the only reliable way. You can throw `Application.DoEvents()` here and there, but file download is a blocking operation, so your form will always seem to be stuck.

Comment: Thanks for reply Anton Gogolev. I am using Application.DoEvents(); but no use

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Threading. You can do your work of calling a .php file in a new thread and in the UI thread you can show a gif image to show to the user that the process is continuing and after thread completes the work you can hide the gif image.

Comment: based on my utility requirements i am not suppose to use threads in my application

Comment: if you stick to not use threading this will not work, not that the whole application interface will hanged while downloading and that is not good.

Comment: I cannot understand why you should not use Threads ,their FREE ,and WebClient is more Advanced than treads if this is a School Task ! PS : If you cant use threads than use BackGroundWorker it is also a thread but not named as .

Comment: Actually this utility for synchronization of offline and online applications. so for that we need to maintain that the flow should be in the same given format. So they are not want to risk by using threads. so they gave me like this requirement not to use threads